# BouncyCastle or OpenSSL to generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with public key only

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle, csr

Is it possible generate a CSR without the key pair or using the public key only, using OpenSSL or BouncyCastle?

Comment: Why would you want to do this (i.e. what is your use case)

Answer (score 0):

According to [certificate signing request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request):

> *The CSR contains information identifying the applicant [...] which must be signed using the applicant's private key.*

and according to what I know of PKI this doesn't make much sense:

You are asking a certificate authority (CA) to confirm your identity but:

- you don't have the information to assure that you are really you (*„without the key pair“*)
- you don't want to give them the certainty that the request has been created by you (*„public key only“*, i.e. no private key to sign)